# use LIKE to search exact word in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

please help., 
Lets say I want to search the word "INK"

when I use LIKE Im getting every word the has the "INK" letters on it including "wrINKled".,

if I use REGEXP I will only get results that has the word 'INK" as the first word.,

I need to be able to search the exact word for example "BLAAAH INK Blah" this product will show because it has the word ink., so as "INK blah blah"..

I cant use FULLTEXT is there a way to do this using LIKE..?

Thank you in advance.. :)

Comment: What does your regex query look like?

Comment: "*I cant use FULLTEXT*" - why not?

Comment: because i wasnt allowed to...

Comment: Regexp is a better answer, you just need the right regexp

Comment: Why is this an off-topic :(

Comment: The OP did demonstrate what s/he tried, why it didn't work, and did provide several examples as to what result s/he expects in various situations. I do not consider the question as off-topic. However some actual code of what s/he actually tried would have been welcome.

Comment: yey :D the off-topic's removed., @RandomSeed thanks for backing up :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query will be

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE column_name LIKE 'INK %' 
    OR column_name LIKE '% INK' 
    OR column_name LIKE '% INK %'
```

Comment: What about at the end of a sentence, like "INK."?

Comment: @Phil OP wants to match `INK` not `INK.`. :)

Comment: @Phil OR column_name LIKE '% INK.'

Comment: "INK." is still the word "INK" in a sentence. For example "The digital medium does not use INK.". You should really be using `FULLTEXT` but barring that, a regex with word boundary flags, eg `\bINK\b`

Comment: @Neeraj There's too many possible grammatical variations to make this feasible with `OR LIKE...` combinations

Comment: @Phil He is just searching from product names

Comment: `... OR column_name LIKE 'INK'`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following regexp to find words:

```
... WHERE your_column REGEXP '[[:<:]]ink[[:>:]]' ;
```

`[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` match word boundaries.

Comment: Am I doing this right..?  $fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item WHERE prodname REGEXP [[:<:]]'$d1'[[:>:]]");

Comment: Nope, sorry I forgot the quotes. These tags must be inside your regex, please see my update in the answer.

Comment: the code is working ., but when I put "INK" inside the variable ex. $product ., Im getting an error...

Comment: Ahh got it., Im missing a parentheses.. :)

Comment: @user, writing just *"Im getting an error..."* without any details is *never* useful. But glad you found the missing parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIKE % INK %` (with leading and trailing spaces)

Comment: This isn't going to match "INK" at the start or end of the string amongst other grammatical considerations.

Comment: ouch., righ.,t this doesnt match the item if the word "INK" is on the start or end... tsk

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE column_name ='INK'
OR column_name LIKE 'INK %' 
OR column_name LIKE '% INK' 
OR column_name LIKE '% INK %'
```

Comment: column_name ='INK' . this condition is not there